# Tracking dependency information across Artifactory repository types

Tags: maven, dependencies, artifactory, conan

While both Maven and Conan store and track metadata with dependency information between Java and C++ packages, respectively, are they able to deal with dependencies that go across the repository types such as JNI dependencies (in either direction - C++ to Java / Java to C++)?

Comment: I don't think so, as either package manager models reference to the other, so doesn't seem possible with Artifactory or any other alternative. Your use case could be interesting for Artifactory JFrog support, I would encourage you to send them your feedback and what you want to do.

Comment: That's a very interesting question. Common usage AFAIK is to publish JNI projects in Maven with the *.so and *.dll attached with a classifier to the main artifact (jar) and its descriptor.
But if a C/C++ project offers a Java interface (through JNI), my assumption is that you have to publish on two sides: the Maven repository for POM/JAR/SO and the Conan repository for SO/A/Headers.
Having some overarching way to tie the publications together would be nice.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  I have put in a email request to JFrog support.  FWIW, I have also considered switching to Ivy which can go across Java and C++ but it does not seem to be in active development anymore unlike Maven and Conan.